# how to remove parameters from url when using dynamic href?

Tags: php, .htaccess, http

passing parameters using

```
$n=isset($_GET['page']) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 0;

echo('<a href="?page='.($n+1).'">Next</a>');
```

hence the url is:

```
home.php?page=2
```

how to remove parameters & *.php file name from url or make

```
"home/browse/" ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you use rewrite engine to avoid it by .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks

#enter code here
IndexIgnore */*

# Turn on RewriteEngine
RewriteEngine On

#  Rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

add .htaccess in root :

> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
>
> RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?MyVar=$1 [QSA,L]

and you can user `$_GET['MyVar']` in your code for examle:

```
$MyVar = isset($_GET['MyVar'])? $_GET['MyVar'] : 'Nop' ;
$Arr= explode('/',$MyVar)  ;
```

after than you have on array of requst in array.